# when setting the UItableview frame in Storyboard it is not changing

Tags: ios, uitableview, storyboard

In my application I am using `storyboard`. In storyboard I have created a `UITableView`, and come to that screen from different views. Based on the view which segues to this view, I need to change my `UITableView` frame, in

```
ViewDidLoad()
{
        [mTableView setFrame:CGRectMake(mTableView.frame.origin.x,50, mTableView.frame.size.width, mScrollView.frame.size.height + mTableView.frame.size.height)];

}
ViewWillAppear() 
{
        [mTableView setFrame:CGRectMake(mTableView.frame.origin.x,50, mTableView.frame.size.width, mScrollView.frame.size.height + mTableView.frame.size.height)];
}
```

I have set the frame for `UITableView`, but it is not considering my frame, it's always taking `storyboard` frame only,

Comment: Are you using constraints / autolayout? Try adding setframe to viewWillLayoutSubviews.

Comment: If you are using autolayout, or constraints, you need to set frames in `viewWillLayoutSubviews`. Otherwise, you cannot change frames until `viewDidAppear` is invoked (as far as I know).